# Why are nginx $scheme and $https always "secure" even when request is not?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to set up a reverse proxy for an app that handles HTTPS redirect itself (i.e. if it notices that the protocol is not HTTPS it will redirect user to secure site):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_redirect default;
        proxy_redirect https://$proxy_host/ https://$host/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

The upstream server needs to know whether the original request was over https or not, which it should know via the X-Forwarded-Proto header, assuming `$scheme` is be "http" on 80 and "https" on 443.

However, it seems that for requests to both 443 *and* port 80 have `$scheme` set to "https" and `$https` set to "on" *always* — i.e. those variables always say the connection is secure even when it's NOT? Are these variables "hardcoded" based on server configuration, and not the actual incoming request?

Comment: They're not. The problem is in your application, not your nginx configuration.

Answer (score 3):

My bad. nginx *does* set `$scheme` (and presumably `$https`) as I would expect, per-request.

The trouble was the following node.js code:

```
var proto = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || (req.connection.encrypted) ? 'https' : 'http';
```

It *looks* correct, but the operator precedence is actually wrong! Should be something like:

```
var proto = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || ((req.connection.encrypted) ? 'https' : 'http');
```

Without the fix, whenever `req.headers['x-forwarded-proto']` was present my local `proto` would get set to "https" even though the header from nginx was correct!